# If Else Statements and Vector Length

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to perform correlations between vectors of unequal length, e.g.,

```
cor(x , y )
```

I want to use the largest possible number of observations for each.
Moreover, I'd like to sample "randomly" from each of the vectors.

In pseudocode:

```
cor( 
   sample(x, size = length(x or y, whichever is smaller), replace = FALSE ) 
 , sample(y, size = length(x or y, whichever is smaller), replace = FALSE )
)
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: `min(length(x), length(y))`? But correlations are typically pairwise, so shuffling `x` and `y` values around doesn't make a lot of sense and you'll get a different answer for each random sample.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware. I am trying to see the consequence of this being done and if it maps onto people's past -- erroneous -- conclusions. Thanks!

Comment: `replicate(10,cor(x,sample(y,length(x))))` or something similar for 10 runs of your code. I doubt there's a need to `sample(x)` as well, but so be it if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this will do what you're asking, but I will question your motivations of not using pairwise correlations:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 15:35

min.of.xy <- min(length(x), length(y))

cor(sample(x, min.of.xy, replace = FALSE),
    sample(y, min.of.xy, replace = FALSE))
```